# How to solve the error: OSError: [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation:'./SpeechCommands\\speech

Tags: python

The project is to make an AI model but I keep having the error while trying to load my code I think. I tried installing some viewers like XPS viewer and Foxit PDF viewer but they didn't work.
This is the code that I think is causing the issues:
'''

```
import csv
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchaudio.datasets import SPEECHCOMMANDS
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import os


QUICK = False


class SubsetSC(SPEECHCOMMANDS):
    def __init__(self, subset: str = None):
        super().__init__("./", download=True)
    def load_list(filename):
        folderpath = os.startfile(self._path, filename)
        with open(folderpath) as folderobj:
            return [os.startfile(self._path, line.strip()) for line in folderobj]

    def load_csv(filename):
        filepath = os.path.join(self._path, filename)
        with open(filepath) as file:
            csvreader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in csvreader:
                print(row)
    if subset == "testing":
        self._walker = load_list("C:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Test data/Test_audio")
    elif subset == "training":
        excludes = load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/udio") + load_csv("c:Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/Train")
        excludes = set(excludes)
        self._walker = [w for w in self._walker if w not in excludes]
    elif subset == "debug":
        excludes = load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/udio_2") + load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Test data/Test_audio")
        excludes = set(excludes)
        self._walker = [self._walker[w] for w in range(len(self._walker)) if self._walker[w] not in excludes and w%10 == 0]
    elif subset == "dev":
        excludes = load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/udio_2") + load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Test data/Test_audio")
        excludes = set(excludes)
        self._walker = [self._walker[w] for w in range(len(self._walker)) if self._walker[w] not in excludes and w%1000 == 0]

def refine(data):
    return [data[i] for i in range(len(data)) if data[i][0].shape[1] == 16000 ]

class SimpleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNet, self).__init__()
        self.n_labels = 35
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(16000, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, self.n_labels)
        )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.net(x)
    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)

def train():
    NUM_EPOCHS = 20
    BATCH_SIZE = 100

working_set = SubsetSC("training")
if QUICK:
    working_set = SubsetSC("dev")
working_set = refine(working_set)
dataloader = DataLoader(working_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
model = SimpleNet()
model.train()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3, weight_decay=1e-5)

for epoch  in range(1, NUM_EPOCHS + 1):
    for features, size, train_labels, serial, train_labels_indices in dataloader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        features = features.reshape(features.shape[0], features.shape[2])
        y_pred = model(features)
        loss = F.nll_loss(y_pred, train_labels_indices)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f'Epoch:{epoch + 1}, Loss:{loss.item():.4f}')

'''
```

and the error that I'm receiving:

```
C:\Users\T0926727H\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torchaudio\backend\utils.py:74: UserWarning: No audio backend is available.   warnings.warn("No audio backend is available.") Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\T0926727H\Desktop\TIL_AI\Model\import torch.py", line 104, in <module>
    model = train()
            ^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\T0926727H\Desktop\TIL_AI\Model\import torch.py", line 68, in train
    working_set = SubsetSC("training")
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\T0926727H\Desktop\TIL_AI\Model\import torch.py", line 33, in
__init__
    excludes = load_list("c:/Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/udio") + load_csv("c:Users/T0926727H/Desktop/TIL_AI/Training data/Train")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\T0926727H\Desktop\TIL_AI\Model\import torch.py", line 20, in load_list
    folderpath = os.startfile(self._path, filename)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ OSError: [WinError 1155] No application is associated with the specified file for this operation: './SpeechCommands\\speech_commands_v0.02'
```

Very sorry if there is a lot here. I'm really not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: the location is wrong? ./SpeechCommands\\speech_commands_v0.02 you have 2 \\ in the path